# Python os library does not see environment variables in Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, operating-system, environment-variables

As you can see on the picture below, I have 'SPARK_HOME' environment variable:

[image]

However I just can't get it through python:

```
import os
os.environ.get('SPARK_HOME', None)  # returns None
"SPARK_HOME" in os.environ          # returns False
```

What am I doing wrong? Operating system is Windows 7
PS: I can get other variables, for example:

```
spark_home = os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH', None)
print spark_home  # returns correct path
```

Comment: @idjaw nice link, honestly I initially tried almost all pieces of code from the linl

Comment: The environment variable editor sends an "Environment" `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message to top-level windows. Explorer see this message and reloads its environment from the registry values; it's pretty much the only program that looks for this message.  Console programs generally don't even own any windows. You need to start a new instance of cmd.exe or python.exe with Explorer as the parent, so it will inherit the updated environment.

Comment: Total Commander looks also for `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` and updates also its own environment variable list which contains also some Total Command related environment variables. That can be seen on starting `cmd.exe` from within Total Commander and run `set`. Then a user or system environment variable is added/modified using Windows System Control Panel and after closing Environment Variables dialog window with button OK, one more `cmd.exe` is started from within Total Commander and `set` is executed also in this second command process instance. The added/modified variable is shown in second cmd.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get your python start seeing new variables you need to restart your console, not just only `ipython notebook`!!!